# windows 7 shared folder asks for password if accessed from XP, why

Tags: windows-xp, password-protection, windows-7-x64, sharing, lan

On a new **W7 Home Premium x64** machine there are several folders shared to lan, all common known settings have been done **to make sharing work without asking for password** but if connecting from other **Windows XP Home computer it keeps asking for password**

- conection set as home network
- in network center settings for home/work set to "sharing does not require password"
- sharing public folders allowed
- tried both "use home groups / use usenames passwords" settings
- shared folder has under advanced sharing options set a permission "Everyone" to read/write
- firewall (Eset Smart Security) is set to allow all tcp/udp in the subnet

computers have static IP's, when i enter address of this machine (192.168.1.1) in the XP pc, it asks me for a password. Giving the username and password from the W7 machine, or using additional credentials added on the W7 machine for network logins, it can open the share, but I don know how to get rid of that? I just want it to work without asking for password.

Too on XP when i click "connect network drive" i can see the W7 machine icon but it does not  show the [+] to view the shares on it (as the damn auth is required)

On XP machines I even checked the "Always use Netbios over TCPIP" but does not make any difference

I managed to connect the network drive on xp by giving the path to the folder on W7 manually by **\\192.168.1.1\sharename** and checking "**use different credentials**" but still some apps using data from this shared folder have problem using it

i even launch a client-setup exe from the share, right after giving in the credentials so i see the files, but the installer tells me data can not be found /its an app specifically made for working on multiple computers using the data in that shared folder /

Comment: I think you can do this by changing the `Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts` setting in GPEdit.msc.

Comment: I will give it a try, will be back on that pc tomorrow... does the Home Premium W7 have GPedit ? is that not only Pro ?  any other ideas to try there? I have to make it work tomorrow :(

Comment: add a user with the same username and password to the other machine.

Comment: damn xp already has user wit diff name but same profile folder name, however another xp machine /xp home/ has other user and still no luck.

Comment: tried gpedit but what should i do? allowe dblank passwords but no luck, also on w7 under profile added credentials /profile settings, click on left/ to match user/password combinations from other machines - no help. Got so far - now the W7 machine seems to remove the everyone from share permissions on the problematic folder - dont know why - i go share - add everyone and set perms, later come back and perms have no everyone - especially root of share may still have it but checking subfolder for share only shows my local account on W7

Comment: best so far as i dont want give my w7 password - xp users can use login combination of network credentials i added under my profile in w7 but no better way found